# ng-change not work for new Date() object

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap

Here is my code

```
<input
class="form-control"
ng-model="a.newTimes[$index]['time']._dateProxy"
ng-change="updateProviderComment(a)"
bs-timepicker
type="text">
```

a.newTimes[$index]['time']._dateProxy is a new Date() object

the point is: function updateProviderComment running only first time, when change time
bug? how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

i have found a lot of problem with the angular strap modules, can i suggest you to use the angular-ui module for the timepicker? i have done something similar to your picker in my application with this module and everything is going ok. take a look [here](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

Answer (score 0):

@mautrok yes, i fully agree with you - angular-ui better (maybe only for now). But regarding design in project we have popover with html content and i can't implement this with angular-ui. I try redefine popover template and use ng-include inside, like this:

```
angular.module("template/popover/popover.html", []).run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache){
    $templateCache.put("template/popover/popover.html", ""
        +"<div class=\"popover popover-appointment {{placement}}\" ng-class=\"{ in: isOpen(), fade: animation() }\">"
        +"<div class=\"arrow\"></div>"
        +"<div class=\"popover-inner\">"
        +"<h3 class=\"popover-title\" ng-bind=\"title\" ng-show=\"title\"></h3>"
        +"<div class=\"popover-content\" ng-controller=\"AppointmentPopoverController\" ng-include src=\"content\"></div>"
        +"</div>"
        +"</div>"
        +"");
}]);
```

it work, but when popover reopen javascript binding gone